# Seleccionar la pelicula (clase) y que se vuelque abajo la informacion de ésta

Tags: php, poo

Tengo una página donde tengo una clase llamada películas y le instancio 10 películas. Luego los paso a un formulario `<select>`.

Ahora quiero que cuando se seleccione la película se vuelque abajo la información de ésta.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
 
<body onload="inicio()">
 
<?php
class pelicula {
    public $nombre;
    public $anio;
    public $director;
    public $esta_Alquilada;
    public $fecha_Dev;
    public $recargo;
    function __construct($nombre='', $anio='', $director='', $esta_Alquilada='', $fecha_Dev=''){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->anio = $anio;
        $this->director = $director;
        $this->esta_Alquilada = $esta_Alquilada;
        $this->fecha_Dev = $fecha_Dev;
    }
    public function leerNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
$obj0 = new pelicula('Lo que el viento se llevo','1950','Victor Fleming', 'si',30/04/2017);
$obj1 = new pelicula('Los Inmortales','1986','Russell Mulcahy','no','');
$obj2 = new pelicula('Guardianes de la Galaxia','2014','James Gunn','si','05/05/2017');
$obj3 = new pelicula('Campo de Sueños','1990','Phil Alden Robinson','si','05/05/2017');
$obj4 = new pelicula('Cadena Perpetua','1995','Frank Darabont','no','');
$obj5 = new pelicula('El Padrino','1990','Francis Ford Coppola','si','05/05/2017');
$obj6 = new pelicula('La lista de Schindler','1994','Steven Spielberg','si','05/05/2017');
$obj7 = new pelicula('Pulp Fiction','1995','Quentin Tarantino','si','05/05/2017');
$obj8 = new pelicula('Matrix','1999','Hermanos Wachowski','no','');
$obj9 = new pelicula('Regreso al Futuro','1985','Robert Zemeckis','no','');
$obj10 = new pelicula('El gran Dictador','1941','Charles Chaplin','si','05/05/2017');
?>
 <div id="caja01">
  <select id="pagina" name="paginas" required>
  <option value="=none" selected>Seleccione una pelicula:</option>
  <?php
  for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
  {
   echo "<option id='ob".$i."' value='ob".$i."'>".${"obj".$i}->leerNombre()."</option>";
  }
  ?>
  </select>
 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que para tu programa vas a necesitar de una base de datos para almacenar tus películas. Luego en tu clase películas tendrías por ejemplo un método `getPeliculas` que consulta a la BD para traerte una lista de películas según un criterio y las envía a la vista para que las muestre en pantalla. Te recomiendo que uses el patrón llamado MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador) que mantiene tu código más organizado, eficaz y fácil de mantener y actualizar. Hay ejemplos muy sencillos buscando en Google de cómo funciona. Revisa las Clases en PHP ya que generalmente las propiedades de arriba son privadas.

Comment: Tu problema no está relacionado con PHP, está relacionado con HTML/CSS3/JS. Ya que no es un formulario que sea enviado al servidor, la interacción directa en el lado del usuario SIEMPRE está relacionado con el frontal HTML/CSS3/JS. Debes corregir ese pequeño trozo de HTML. Además, te recomiendo no usar atajos como `${"obj".$i}`. En su lugar podrías haber creado una matriz donde agregar las películas.

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar tu problema necesitas:

- Generar bajo la selección los datos que quieres que se muestren tras pulsar en una selección.
- Ocultar esa información a la vista mientras no se seleccione (en mi ejemplo uso `display: none`).
- Responder al evento `onchange` de la selección para provocar que la información seleccionada se muestre (en mi ejemplo, usando `display: block` en el selector `:target`).

He aquí el ejemplo propuesto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.detalles {
    display: none;
}
.detalles:target {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="inicio()">

<?php
class pelicula {
    public $nombre;
    public $anio;
    public $director;
    public $esta_Alquilada;
    public $fecha_Dev;
    public $recargo;
    function __construct($nombre='', $anio='', $director='', $esta_Alquilada='', $fecha_Dev=''){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->anio = $anio;
        $this->director = $director;
        $this->esta_Alquilada = $esta_Alquilada;
        $this->fecha_Dev = $fecha_Dev;
    }
    public function leerNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
$obj0 = new pelicula('Lo que el viento se llevo','1950','Victor Fleming', 'si',30/04/2017);
$obj1 = new pelicula('Los Inmortales','1986','Russell Mulcahy','no','');
$obj2 = new pelicula('Guardianes de la Galaxia','2014','James Gunn','si','05/05/2017');
$obj3 = new pelicula('Campo de Sueños','1990','Phil Alden Robinson','si','05/05/2017');
$obj4 = new pelicula('Cadena Perpetua','1995','Frank Darabont','no','');
$obj5 = new pelicula('El Padrino','1990','Francis Ford Coppola','si','05/05/2017');
$obj6 = new pelicula('La lista de Schindler','1994','Steven Spielberg','si','05/05/2017');
$obj7 = new pelicula('Pulp Fiction','1995','Quentin Tarantino','si','05/05/2017');
$obj8 = new pelicula('Matrix','1999','Hermanos Wachowski','no','');
$obj9 = new pelicula('Regreso al Futuro','1985','Robert Zemeckis','no','');
$obj10 = new pelicula('El gran Dictador','1941','Charles Chaplin','si','05/05/2017');
?>
    <div id="caja01">
        <select id="pagina" name="paginas" required
          onchange="location.hash = 'detalles' + this.value;">
        <option value="=none" selected>Seleccione una pelicula:</option>
        <?php
        for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            echo "<option id='ob".$i."' value='ob".$i."'>".${"obj".$i}->leerNombre()."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>

    </div>
        <?php
        for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            echo "<div id='detallesob".$i."' class='detalles'>Detalles de: ".${"obj".$i}->leerNombre()."</div>";
        }
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Las partes destacables del código son:

```
<style>
.detalles {
    display: none;
}
.detalles:target {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Defino la clase que usarán los `<div>` que mostrarán los detalles, ocultando su contenido por defecto. Si son enlazados (agregando `#id` en la URL) se usará el selector `:target`, mostrando su contenido.

```
<select id="pagina" name="paginas" required
  onchange="location.hash = 'detalles' + this.value;">
```

Reacciono al evento `onchange` cambiando el enlace interno (hash) al `<div>` relacionado con los detalles de esa selección.

```
echo "<div id='detallesob".$i."' class='detalles'>Detalles de: ".${"obj".$i}->leerNombre()."</div>";
```

Genero un `<div>` asociado a cada película y muestro en su interior los detalles deseados.

---

**Solución sin usar PHP**

```js
angular.module('peliculasApp', [])
 .controller('peliculasCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.peliculas = peliculas;
 }
]);

var peliculas = {
  "0": {
    "nombre": "Lo que el viento se llevo",
    "anio": "1950",
    "director": "Victor Fleming",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "30\/04\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "1": {
    "nombre": "Los Inmortales",
    "anio": "1986",
    "director": "Russell Mulcahy",
    "esta_Alquilada": "no",
    "fecha_Dev": "",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "2": {
    "nombre": "Guardianes de la Galaxia",
    "anio": "2014",
    "director": "James Gunn",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "3": {
    "nombre": "Campo de Sue\u00f1os",
    "anio": "1990",
    "director": "Phil Alden Robinson",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "4": {
    "nombre": "Cadena Perpetua",
    "anio": "1995",
    "director": "Frank Darabont",
    "esta_Alquilada": "no",
    "fecha_Dev": "",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "5": {
    "nombre": "El Padrino",
    "anio": "1990",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "6": {
    "nombre": "La lista de Schindler",
    "anio": "1994",
    "director": "Steven Spielberg",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "7": {
    "nombre": "Pulp Fiction",
    "anio": "1995",
    "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "8": {
    "nombre": "Matrix",
    "anio": "1999",
    "director": "Hermanos Wachowski",
    "esta_Alquilada": "no",
    "fecha_Dev": "",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "9": {
    "nombre": "Regreso al Futuro",
    "anio": "1985",
    "director": "Robert Zemeckis",
    "esta_Alquilada": "no",
    "fecha_Dev": "",
    "recargo": null
  },
  "10": {
    "nombre": "El gran Dictador",
    "anio": "1941",
    "director": "Charles Chaplin",
    "esta_Alquilada": "si",
    "fecha_Dev": "05\/05\/2017",
    "recargo": null
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="peliculasApp" ng-controller="peliculasCtrl">
  <select id="pagina" name="pagina"
    ng-options="pelicula.nombre for pelicula in peliculas"
    ng-model="elegido"
  ><option value="">- [ Seleccione una película ] -</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-show="elegido" style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;">
    <p>Nombre: {{elegido.nombre}}<br/>
    Año: {{elegido.anio}}<br/>
    Director: {{elegido.director}}</p>
    <pre style="border: 1px dashed orange">{{elegido | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que este ejemplo te ilustre un poco más lo que puedes conseguir con frameworks del lado del cliente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar, he entendido tu planteamiento, pero no habrá una manera de que cogiendo el select por jquery por ejemplo con esta instruccion:    var opcion = $('option:selected').text();,     pase ese valor a php y lo compare con un if con todas las pelis para volcar solo la información de esa peli.?

Comment: Claro, pero en ese caso necesitas varios scripts PHP. Te recomendaría que uno de ellos contuviera la definición de los datos (para ser compartidos entre los dos restantes), otro para generar el HTML que verá el cliente y uno adicional para recibir las peticiones XHR. ¿Es realmente necesario hacer eso? Si hablamos de rehacer el código entonces se plantean más cosas: ¿no sería más sencillo guardar esa información en una base de datos? y si quieres tener todo de golpe, ¿no sería mejor enviarle toda la información al cliente y que se ejecute en local el trabajo sobre los datos?

Comment: De una forma u otra hay frameworks tanto del lado del motor (backend) como de la interfaz (frontend) que podrían ayudarte con tu tarea. Por ejemplo, con angular.js podrías ahorrarte muchísimo código para cambio dinámico del contenido de la página.

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo usando Angular.js, para que le eches un vistazo.